# Styling select tags and background with select2

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I want to style my `select` element with CSS. I want to style the tags so they have a blue background color, but the blue background color isn't working.

Here is my CSS:

```
.select2-search-choice {
  border-style: none;
  color: #D6D6D6;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The border style isn't working eiether. Also, I would also like to make the background of the searchbox a different color, it would be helpful if someone listed all the select2 CSS classes and what they style, since the docs aren't a big help.

**Right now**

[image]

Comment: .select2-selection__rendered > .select2-selection__choice{  } -- give this a try

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide a working jsFiddle to help you better !